# How do you place a class in the default package in netbeans for Mac?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

My instructor requires us to take the package from our code and make it a default package. The only problem is he taught us how to do that through Windows and I have a MacBook so his way isn't working. I can't figure out how to do it. I've attached the code to the bottom in case that will help.

```
package romannumeralcalculator;

import java.util.*;

public class RomanNumeralCalculator 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int integer;

        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter an interger from 1 to 5999. Enter a negative number to exit. \n ->");
            integer = input.nextInt();

        } while (integer >= 6000);

        while (integer == 0) {

            System.out.println("");
            break;
        }

        String results = "";
        int ones = integer % 10;
        int tens = (integer / 10) % 10;
        int hundreds = (integer / 100) % 10;
        int thousands = (integer / 1000) % 1000;

        switch (thousands) {
            case 1:
                results += "M";

                break;

            case 2:
                results += "MM";

                break;
            case 3:
                results += "MMM";

                break;

            case 4:
                results += "MMMM";

                break;

            case 5:
                results += "MMMMM";

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("");
        }

        switch (hundreds) {
            case 1:
                results += "C";

                break;
            case 2:
                results += "CC";

                break;
            case 3:
                results += "CCC";

                break;
            case 4:
                results += "CD";

                break;
            case 5:
                results += "D";

                break;
            case 6:
                results += "DC";

                break;
            case 7:
                results += "DCC";

                break;
            case 8:
                results += "DCCC";

                break;
            case 9:
                results += "CM";

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("");
        }
        switch (tens) {
            case 1:
                results += "X";

                break;
            case 2:
                results += "XX";

                break;
            case 3:
                results += "XXX";

                break;
            case 4:
                results += "XL";

                break;
            case 5:
                results += "L";

                break;
            case 6:
                results += "LX";

                break;
            case 7:
                results += "LXX";

                break;
            case 8:
                results += "LXXX";

                break;
            case 9:
                results += "XC";

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("");
        }

        switch (ones) {
            case 1:
                results += "I";

                break;
            case 2:
                results += "II";

                break;
            case 3:
                results += "III";

                break;
            case 4:
                results += "IV";

                break;
            case 5:
                results += "V";

                break;
            case 6:
                results += "VI";

                break;
            case 7:
                results += "VII";

                break;
            case 8:
                results += "VIII";

                break;
            case 9:
                results += "IX";

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("");
        }

        System.out.println(results);
    }
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you remove `package romannumeralcalculator;`?

Comment: In java when you don't declare a package it is considered to be a default package. Now in your case you just need to remove the package name and move directory to appropriate place. It doesn't matter whether you are using windows or mac. directory structure representing your package structure would remain same.

Comment: Your instructor should be made aware that "The use of the default package is discouraged." ;-) Classes that are not in a package can't be referenced from classes that are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the projects tab of Netbeans in the top-left:

1. Expand the tree for your Project.
2. Expand the `Source Packages` folder.
3. Expand the package with your java file.
4. Drag the java file from under the package to the `Source Packages` folder.
5. A dialog box will pop up with the title `Move Class`. On that dialog click the `Refactor` button.

This should be the same procedure in Windows. I am not sure why your professor told you something different.